Django "CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set." when I change the request.user in my custom middleware
This is my custom middleware. The CSRF error only occurs because of request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: request_user). Please help me fix this
Custom middleware:
import jwt
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class JWTAuthentication:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        if not token:
            token_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
            if not token_header:
                return self.get_response(request)
            if 'Bearer ' in token_header:
                token = token_header.split('Bearer ')[1]

        try:
            decoded = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return self.get_response(request)
        
        user_id = decoded.get('id')
        if user_id:
            User = get_user_model()
            request_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: request_user) # i get CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set when i change the request.user, fix this

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response


settings middlewares:
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'myauth.middlewares.JWTAuthentication',
]

I tried commenting the request.user modification and the CSRF returns no error. I also tried includeing the X-Csrftoken in the headers in postman and it works well, but it doesn't work when I use axios even though I included the X-Csrftoken in the headers, and it was showed in the networks tab that it was sent as a header.
